# Calculate (express without infinite sum): $\frac{2}{1\cdot3}-\frac{4}{2 \cdot 9} + \frac{8}{3\cdot 27}- \frac{16}{4 \cdot 81} + ...$

Tags: calculus, analysis, summation, taylor-expansion

This is no homework, it's a task from an old exam and I'm wondering how it's solved correctly.

> Calculate (express without infinite sum):
>   $$\frac{2}{1\cdot3}-\frac{4}{2 \cdot 9} + \frac{8}{3\cdot 27}-
> \frac{16}{4 \cdot 81} + ...$$

We aren't allowed to use the sum symbol, so to be honest I got no idea how to do it.

I assume we are actually supposed to say what the limit of that is going to be? Because it's saying "calculate". I cannot imagine we can calculate this exactly, so I believe it's really the limit.

I have realized the signs are always switching, so for this we already got $(-1)^{n}$. Furthermore, the numerator will be greater than the denominator. This means this will always become smaller, will go towards zero.

But if we take the total sum / difference, we won't get zero because the beginning isn't small...

In total we will get to $0.5$ I believe.

But that way I described, would it count as solution and is it correct at all?

Comment: What's the point of not using sigma notation? It's just a means of notation, not a means of proof. You could just do it all with sigma notation and then switch it to ellipses. I don't see the point.

Comment: Do you know the Taylor series of $x \mapsto \log (1+x)$?

Comment: No I don't but I had in mind it could be done with taylor. But I cannot imagine how.

Comment: I'm assuming they mean the *final expression* can not use the sum symbol.  To forbid the sigma and demand elipses is pointless and perverse.  And I'd just answer it by say N = a +........  .  Which is clearly not the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$S(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}2^n}{n3^n}=-\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^n}{n}, x = -\dfrac{2}{3}$. You can differentiate $S$ and integrate it.Can you continue? or using Log.

Comment: But I see sum symbol in your solution? Or I should continue using taylor on this?

Comment: when you differentiate it, it will be a geometric sum and you can find a closed form.

Comment: @cnmesr You can literally just replace his sigma notation with your notation and it's the same proof.

Comment: Jam how you mean exactly? Please make answer I want give you + also for help

Comment: Because we arent allowed use integration

Comment: DeepSea deserves the +1, not me. What I'm saying is that $\Sigma_n(x^n/n!)$ is identical to $(x^1/1!)+(x^2/2!)+\dots$, they're just different ways of notating the same thing.

Comment: @cnmesr Notation is not math.  Notation is a language.

Comment: I honestly believe you misunderstood the forbidance of the sum symbol.  Not the *final* answer does *not* have the sum symbol.  I am absolutely *certain* that is what they meant.

Comment: @cnmesr Then use Taylor's theorem in reverse on the given sum above through differential equations, which would avoid integration I guess.  Just way more messy that way though.

Comment: People wait, I can make the task, my end solution can be with sum symbol..?!

Comment: @cnmesr um, no?  what fleablood means is the following: $$1+2=2+1$$they simply don't want you to repeat the question reworded differently.  But any method to get to the solution should be fine.  Sum symbol avoidance like simply saying "one plus two equals two plus one".

Comment: No, I said the *final* solution can *NOT* have the sum symbol.  But I can not see any reason on earth that you shouldn't be able to use the sum symbol to *get* to your final solution.

Comment: All this talk about a "final solution" is getting me worried

Comment: Okay, "final answer" if we prefer Regis Philbin.

Comment: Suppose you were asked "Calculate $1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + ....$.  Express without an infinite sum".  That simply means your *answer* can not be "$1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + ..... = 1 3/4 + (1/8 + 1/16 + 1/32 + ......)$"  That answer *is* correct but misses the point.  They want the answer to not be an infinite sum.  It doesn't make the slightest difference what notation you use to get to the result.  It's just that the *result* can not be an infinite sum.

Comment: @Jam Have a cup of tea.